# MySQL utf8_general can't store Chinese characters?

Tags: mysql, utf-8

I was trying to store some chinese characters into mysql table.

they become something like this:

```
&#28872;&#28779;&#38596;&#24515;
```

They work fine when I output them in innerhtml, but if it's an html attribute, they won't show the chinese characters.

Strangely, if I saved the data in utf8_bin or utf8_unicode, they works ok.

Any fix to this?

To be more specific, I'm using codeIgniter when doing this.

Comment: How are you trying to store the data into the database? It looks like you're HTML-escaping them before they get stored.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm not sure, but when I try to do html_entity_decode, it doesn't decode into anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456313/cant-insert-chinese-character-into-mysql/43389703#43389703

Answer (score 1):

just making sure your table is ready for Chinese characters:

Go to your mysql table and change the "Character set" to "**gb2312**" and "Collation" to "**gb2312_chinese_ci**".

For me, I did it on a "row" level and not the whole table, since only I was only expecting Chinese characters in 1 field of my table.

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-cjk.html)

Let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Just modify the field's Collation to utf8_general.