# Can't insert Chinese character into MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, character-encoding

The cookie is encoded using the big5 set, and it cannot insert into MySQL. Could you help me to solve this problem?

Fields: `username` is eng, `date1` is date, `reason1` is a Chinese character.

```
$reason1 = $_COOKIE["reason"];
$sql2="INSERT INTO 
    attendance_count(username,date,count_time,appendix) 
    VALUES ('$username','$date1','0','$reason1')";
mysql_query($sql2);
```

Comment: What is the exact error message? use `mysqli_error()` to get it. Also it is better to use the new mysqli functions as the old mysql functions will be deprecated.

Comment: [SQL Injection read about it...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Yeah, that website won't last an hour in the wild.

Comment: I found the solution here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?132,578240,579233

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use **UTF-8** when you create table.

```
create table table_name () CHARACTER SET = utf8;
```

Use **UTF-8** when you insert to table

```
set username utf8; INSERT INTO table_name (ABC,VAL);
```

[**Read More**](http://www.tanzilo.com/2008/10/13/php-mysql-unicode-solution-to-chinese-russian-or-any-language/)

[**And More**](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD/Configuring+UTF8+Character+Set+for+MySQL)

**Detailed Code**

Below code is tested code please do the following its works.

If you have already created database please ALTER it as below code.
And if you didn't created database then create it and set  Collation to utf8_unicode_ci

And same for table define Collation as "utf8_unicode_ci" for table fields in which you want to store chines chars.

```
ALTER DATABASE `stackoverflow` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `stackoverflow`.`chines`
(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    `words` VARCHAR( 200 ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

```
<?php

    define('HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
    define('USERNAME', 'root');
    define('PASSWORD', '');
    define('DATABASE', 'stackoverflow');

    $dbLink = mysql_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $dbLink)or die(mysql_error());
    mb_language('uni'); 
    mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
    mysql_select_db(DATABASE, $dbLink)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("set names 'utf8'",$dbLink)or die(mysql_error());

    if(isset($_POST['addWord']))
    {
        mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $dbLink)or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $dbLink)or die(mysql_error());

        $sql_query = "INSERT INTO chines(words) VALUES('".$_POST['words']."')";
        mysql_query($sql_query, $dbLink)or die(mysql_error());
    }

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $dbLink);
        $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM chines";
        $dbResult = mysql_query( $sql_query, $dbLink)or die(mysql_error());

    ?>

    <form action="" method="post">

        <p>Word : <input type="text" name="words" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="addWord" /></p>

    </form>
    <?php
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($dbResult))
        {
            echo $row['words']. '<br />';
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

See the result and step visual as below.

[image]

Comment: mysqli_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $db);

Comment: or you can just do it by alter table field from phpmyadmin and set type to UTF-8...example ..  ALTER TABLE t MODIFY col1 CHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8;

Comment: mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $dbLink);
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $dbLink);

Comment: http://www.tanzilo.com/2008/10/13/php-mysql-unicode-solution-to-chinese-russian-or-any-language/ please follow every single step from this link it will help a lot in mean time i m writing code for same.

Comment: @DipeshParmar , Hi Dipesh , its working fine in mysql database successfully , i want to do the same concept in oracle database using php. what do i need to do?please help me on this.i have raised question please look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39015528/storing-chinese-character-in-oracle-using-ajax-is-not-working/39038863#39038863)

Answer (score 5):

For Chinese, you really need `utf8mb4`, not `utf8`.  This is because of a small number of Chinese characters that require 4-byte UTF8 characters, which MySQL's `utf8` does not support.

Comment: mysql says `(1115, "Unknown character set: 'utf8mb4'")`, mysql-v5.1.71 here.

Comment: Then you must update to at least 5.5.  (5.5.3 is when utf8mb4 became available -- about a decade ago).

Comment: a friend sent me this and saved me after hours of googling, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is about the cookie being encoded `big5`?  Is the rest of the data *in the client* encoded as `utf8`?  If 'yes' to both, ...

Change the connection to be `big5`, do the `INSERT`/`SELECT` of the cookie, then change back to utf8 (or, better, utf8mb4 after upgrading).

Executing `SET NAMES big5` or calling the `charset('big5')` function for the API you are using is the preferred way to switch back and forth.

(Meanwhile, get away from the `mysql_*` interface; switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`.)

If everything in the client is `big5`, then there is no need to switch back and forth.  Simply declare that the client is using big5.  Note:  It does not matter whether the table/column is also big5; MySQL will convert between them.

Answer (score 0):

update character set of table columns as well with utf8 along with table character set. May be check in Mysql workbench alter table and see character set of columns you want to support Chinese characters.

Answer (score 0):

for those who using c# connector in Visual Studio having difficulty insert chinese character into mysql database.
(解决 MySQL 无法正常 insert 中文字题, 出现???乱码)

symptom ie.
in C# query string

query = $@"INSERT INTO my_table
SET name = '**草泥马**' ;"

after insert successful
in mysql table show
name = **???**

## Solution in mysql workbench

got edit table mode

1. below tale name
   make sure table 'charset/collection' **set to 'utf8mb4' and 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'**
2. select the 'name' row,
   below column name choose **'charset/collection' and 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'**
   then hit **Apply**

back to visual studio.

3. in c# connetion string add "Charset=utf8;"
   ie.
   String connectionString = "SERVER=your_serverip;Port=3306;DATABASE=my_database;UID=user;PASSWORD=pw;;Allow User Variables=True;SslMode=none;**Charset=utf8**";

it should work. hope it help you.

Answer (score 0):

The collation for Chinese characters is `gb18030_chinese_ci` (Chinese, case-insensitive).
You need to update the table with the above collation.