# How can i display chines characters from mySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm helping for my school website,and then i try to display some data form the database,the image source and link is work just fine,but when try to display some chines string,is became `?????`,my PHP document is already using UTF-8 and same as SQL `utf8_unicode_ci`,but is still showing some `?????`

Showing content code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
$getNews = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news");
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($getNews)) {
$img = $rows['img'];
$title = $rows['title'];
$link = $rows['link'];
echo '<div class="showNewsBox">';
  echo '<div class="showNews">';
   echo "<a href='$link' target='_blank'>";
    echo "<img src='$img' class='newsImage'>";
    echo "<h3 class='newsTitle'>" . $title . "</h3>";
   echo "</a>";
 echo "</div>";
}
```

PHP UTF-8 code

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Then the Chinese in your database is *not* in UTF-8.

Comment: So how i can set they become UTF-8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 0):

I think most voted answer of this question below will solve your problem:
[Can't insert Chinese character into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456313/cant-insert-chinese-character-into-mysql)

In short:
set charset as UTF-8 when reading and writing to DB

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_client=utf8", $dbLink); 
mysql_query("SET character_set_connection=utf8", $dbLink);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just go to your database table structure and set collation `utf8_unicode_ci` for column which you want to display in chines!