# Storing chinese character in oracle using ajax is not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, oracle

I want to store chinese characters from an html page into oracle database using ajax concept.

```
Front end : HTML & PHP.
Back end  : Oracle 11G.
```

Oracle Characteristics:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE = AMERICA
NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8MSWIN1252
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET = AL16UTF16
```

when I try to store chinese character using form submit it's storing successfully, if I try to store through ajax I am getting weird characters in the database.

In the ajax page I have added this line:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

and in the html page added the below line:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I have gone through many stack overflow suggestions but no luck.

Please advice me on how to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Code:**HTML Code.**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function addForm()
    {
      var english=document.getElementById('txt_english').value;
      var id=document.getElementById('txt_id').value;
      var chinese=document.getElementById('txt_chinese').value;
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          async: false,
          url: "ajax/ajax_add_form.php",
          data:
          {
            english: english,
            chinese: chinese,
            id: id
          }
        }).done(
        function (html){
            alert(html);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type='text' name='txt_id' id='txt_id' value='' /><br>
    <input type='text' name='txt_english' id='txt_english' value='' />                          
    <input type='text' name='txt_chinese' id='txt_chinese' value='' /> 
    <button type="button" onclick="addForm()">Click Me!</button> 
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP Code: **ajax/ajax_add_form.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
include("../config.php");
extract($_REQUEST);
$sql=oci_parse($conn,"insert into  test(id,english,chinese1)values(:id,:english,:chinese)");
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':id', $id); 
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':english', $english); 
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':chinese', $chinese);
oci_execute($sql);
echo "success";
?>
```

[image]

**My Issue:**

Even though it stores in another format when i get back in web page its working and displays correctly.

My problem is another tool called agile is also accessing the same data , hence there conversion is not happening it displays what ever data format is stored in database.

Hence i want to store exactly as user enters , no need of any conversion.

Comment: Set environment variable `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`

Comment: datatype should be nvarchar  or Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("NLS_LANG", "CHINESE_CHINA.WE8ISO8859P1", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)

Comment: @WernfriedDomschei i tried setting that environment but i got cannot access NLS data file or invalid environment specified. my current system locale is Chinese (Simplified,PRC) , my problem is even though its store in some other format when display in web page its showing perfectly. but this same data can access through other Agile tool there its shows the format which stored in DB , i mean bad format.

Comment: @ManishGoswami  i tried setting that environment but i got cannot access NLS data file or invalid environment specified. my current system locale is Chinese (Simplified,PRC) , my problem is even though its store in some other format when display in web page its showing perfectly. but this same data can access through other Agile tool there its shows the format which stored in DB , i mean bad format.hence i want to store as user enters.

Comment: Did you really set `NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8`? For testing you can also try `NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8`. Ensure data type of column `chinese` is `NVARCHAR2` (not `VARCHAR2`) because character set WE8MSWIN1252 does not support any Chinese characters.

Comment: @ManishGoswami, for sure character set `WE8ISO8859P1` will **not** work for Chinese characters. Also NLS-Language `CHINESE` does not exist in Oracle, use either `SIMPLIFIED CHINESE` or `TRADITIONAL CHINESE`. Check with `SELECT * FROM V$NLS_VALID_VALUES WHERE parameter = 'LANGUAGE';`

Comment: You should use prepared statement with bind parameters, i.e. `$sql=oci_parse($conn,"insert into test(id,english,chinese)values(:id, :en, :cn)");
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':id', $id);
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':en', $english);
oci_bind_by_name($sql, ':cn', $chinese);`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit , i tried you suggestion still data gets storing in other format, please check the screen short which i added.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you've set your `OCI` connection to use UTF-8:

```
oci_connect($username, $password, $connection_string, 'UTF8');
```

This tells Oracle the charset encoding you are sending and expect to receive. Oracle then takes care of 'translating' between the server and the client automatically. From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-connect.php) (emphasis mine):

> Determines the character set used by the Oracle Client libraries. The character set does not need to match the character set used by the database. **If it doesn't match, Oracle will do its best to convert data to and from the database character set**. Depending on the character sets this may not give usable results. Conversion also adds some time overhead.

The only thing you then need to take care of is that your PHP application treats everything as UTF-8.

Comment: i tried the above code,but no luck :-( , i have added screen short please check

Comment: @ArchanaPalani Double check that all of your PHP files are saved in UTF-8 (not ANSI).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

instead of

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" value="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Comment: i tired the above suggestion , still the same probelm , am i missing anything from oracle side ? , because i tried all possible ways to solve but nothing is helping me.