# mysql can't display chinese

Tags: php, mysql, sql, character-encoding

When I want to input some Chinese character into my form,

```
<html>
<title>
Form
</title>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<form action="form.php" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" >
<p>Input: <input type="text" name="input1" /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


</div>
</body>
</html>`
```

and the form.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

define('DB_NAME','form1');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

$link= mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link){
    die('could not connect server'.mysql_error());  
} 

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$link);

if(!$db_selected){
    die('Cannot connect'.DB_NAME.': '.mysql_error());
}

$value=$_POST['input1'];

$sql="INSERT INTO form (input1) VALUES ('$value')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: '.mysql_error());
}


mysql_close();
header("Location: form.htm");
?>
```

Mysql sheet output something strange like 早&#2621
Why?
Should I do something on the code or on Mysql?
Please help!!!!
Thanks!!!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456313/cant-insert-chinese-character-into-mysql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't insert Chinese character into MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456313/cant-insert-chinese-character-into-mysql)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: Do _not_ use the `mysql_*` interface; switch to PDO or `mysqli_*`.

Comment: `&#2621;` is a "html entity"; how did the `;` vanish?  Let's see the SQL that put the string into the table and got it out.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use this line after your database connection ?

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
```

Like this...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

define('DB_NAME','form1');
define('DB_USER','root');
define('DB_PASSWORD','');
define('DB_HOST','localhost');

$link= mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
if (!$link){
    die('could not connect server'.mysql_error());  
} 
...
...
```