# Unable to insert UTF-8 characters in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, utf-8, rss

I am trying to insert some UTF-8 characters into MYsql database and every time i am inserting , i am getting `???? ???` like output as column values

I am using RSS handler to parse RSS xml URL and also getting `?????` like output in eclipse

```
 code is like this:

    SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
    T handler = null;
    handler=handlerClass.newInstance();
    String rssUrl="https://www.gazabpost.com/rss/category/entertainment";
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new 
        URL(rssUrl).openStream(),"UTF-8"));
    InputSource is = new InputSource(reader);
    is.setEncoding("UTF-8");
    saxParser.parse(is, handler);
    return handler.getRSSItemList();
```

also the database encoding is like this :

```
character_set_client     utf8
character_set_connection utf8
character_set_database   latin1
character_set_filesystem binary
character_set_results    utf8
character_set_server     latin1
character_set_system     utf8
character_sets_dir       /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

Do i need to change the `character_set_database` parameter ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Check this question out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405236/jdbc-mysql-utf-8-string-writing-problem

Comment: but i don't want to change the character encoding of whole scema , maybe a table will do

Comment: Changing the character_set_server to utf8 will not cause any remedies at all.

Comment: i checked `show create table in workbench` , it has default character set to utf8 already

Comment: Your server needs to coop with that too,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456313/cant-insert-chinese-character-into-mysql/43389703#43389703

Comment: See "question marks" in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored