# Post array data into database in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to record equipment in many forms, but errors always occur.
Undefined index: name

```
public function EquipCheck(Request $request) {
    $user = User::where('username', $request -> username) -> firstOrFail();
    if ($request -> token == $user -> token) {
        $item_detail_id = CheckLog::where('user_id', $user -> id) -> orderBy('id', 'desc') -> first() -> item_detail_id;
        $new_form = new Form;
        $new_form -> item_detail_id = $item_detail_id;
        $new_form -> user_id = User::where('username', $request -> username) -> firstOrFail() -> id;
        $new_form -> created_time = Carbon::now() -> format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $new_form -> save();
        $form = Form::with('eqpt') -> where('item_detail_id', $item_detail_id) -> orderBy('created_time', 'desc') -> first();

        $data = $request -> eqpt;
        $i = 0;
        $sql = array();

        while($i < count($cyldata['serie'])){
            $sql[] = array(
                'form_id' => $form -> id,
                'name' => $data['name'][$i],
                'unit' => $data['unit'][$i],
                'quantity' => $data['quantity'][$i],
                'check_quantity' => $data['check_quantity'][$i],
            );
            $i++;
        }

        DB::table('eqpt') -> insert($sql);

        return "Success";
    }
}
```

When I use the following code, the database can be inserted the array.

```
$dataSet[] = [
            'form_id' => $form -> id,
            'name' => 'test',
            'unit' => 'box',
            'quantity' => 20,
            'check_quantity' => 20,
        ];

        DB::table('eqpt') -> insert($dataSet);
```

[This is post data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfIpK.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the `$data` variable after you set it? Also, where is `$cyldata['serie']` being set?

Comment: How can I recreate array from the post data?

Comment: have you created dd($data)? can you let us know the result?

Comment: It might be an issue of character set collation, have you tried changing the character set and collation? This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456313/cant-insert-chinese-character-into-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$data** contains an array of objects. **$data['name']** refers to the property of that array, while you should access properties of objects in that array.

Replace

```
$sql[] = array(
  'form_id' => $form -> id,
  'name' => $data['name'][$i],
  'unit' => $data['unit'][$i],
  'quantity' => $data['quantity'][$i],
  'check_quantity' => $data['check_quantity'][$i],
);
```

with

```
$sql[] = array(
  'form_id' => $form -> id,
  'name' => $data[$i]['name'],
  'unit' => $data[$i]['unit'],
  'quantity' => $data[$i]['quantity'],
  'check_quantity' => $data[$i]['check_quantity'],
);
```

Comment: Good catch - I hadn't seen that OP had transposed the keys.